# Can't get Rails Server to work with MySQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get my Rails application to work with MySQL and not default SQLite.  I've created a new project that forces the use MySQL which seemed to work correctly.

It added gem entry in the Gem file as so:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

    # Bundle edge Rails instead:
    # gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

    gem 'mysql2'
```

And when I run the bundle command it shows that its using mysql gem:

```
Using mysql2 <0.3.11>
```

I've also configure the database.yml file as so:

```
development:
 adapter: mysql2
 encoding: utf8
 reconnect: false
 database: dbname
 pool: 5
 username: uname
 password: pass
 host: hostname

test:
 development:
 adapter: mysql2
 encoding: utf8
 reconnect: false
 database: dbname
 pool: 5
 username: uname
 password: pass
 host: hostname

production:
 development:
 adapter: mysql2
 encoding: utf8
 reconnect: false
 database: dbname
 pool: 5
 username: uname
 password: pass
 host: hostname
```

But when I try to run the rails server I get this:

> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/l
>   ib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `require': 126: The specified module could
>   not be found .   -
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-min
>   gw32/lib/mysql2/1.9/mysql2.so (LoadError)
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-
>   x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in`'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-
>   x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `require'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-
>   x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in`'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
>   lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
>   lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in`block (2 levels) in require'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
>   lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
>   lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in`block in require'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
>   lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
>   lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in`require'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4/
>   lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
>           from C:/Users/n00151956/Desktop/RubyProjects/Demo/config/application.rb:
>   7:in`'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in`block in '
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in`'
>           from script/rails:6:in `require'
>           from script/rails:6:in`'

I was able to get the rails server running with default SQLite but for the life of me I can't get it working with MySQL.  If anyone can help me out with this that would be great help!

Thanks

Comment: Try running `bundle exec rails server`

Comment: It returns the same thing.

Comment: have you download **MySQL Connector/C** and then copy `libmysql.dll`  from it to your railsinstaller installation ?

Comment: No, how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download libmysql.dll file from - [mysql-connector](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip/from/pick) and put it in C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin should be here [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIhEj.png)
2. open command prompt as administrator and start the mysql server the following way: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysql

**Update**

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: proj_development
  username: root
  password: pass
  host: 127.0.0.1
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: proj_test
  username: root
  password: pass
  host: 127.0.0.1
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: proj_production
  username: root
  password: pass
  host: 127.0.0.1
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: When I run the 2nd command I get this error:  ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Comment: What if MySQL is not running on localhost?  I have it running on a different server.

Comment: well going by that error you gave me I quote `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)` this shows that clearly your application is trying to connect to your localhost. But if your MySQL is running on a different server then put the correct hostname. By default it will try to connect to localhost

Comment: I've specified the full hostname inside the database.yml file, but its still not working

Comment: Okay from further research it seems that from the MySQL website - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html It states that:

The error (2003) Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server' (10061) indicates that the network connection has been refused. 
You should check that there is a MySQL server running, that it has network connections enabled, and that the network port you specified is the one configured on the server.

Comment: I think I'm just going to resort to using SQLite for now.  This doesn't seem to be working.  Thanks for the helping, its always appreciated.

Comment: @Nick See the update I added the socket: The purpose of this is by specifying the socket Rails, or rather the database driver, will use the socket instead of a network connection. It can be quicker to use the socket. Give it a shot see what happens. No worries

Answer (score 1):

[Install Mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql) If you not have installation it.

1. Download [MySQL-connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) (zip file) - download noinstall version (not for install).  You should extract it to `c:\mysql-connector-c-your-version-download`
2. copy `libmysql.dll` from `c:\mysql-connector-c-your-version-download` to `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin`
3. Install MySQL gem

   `gem install mysql --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-dir=C:/mysql-connector-c-your-version-download`