# Rails generate command error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.3

I am trying to use the Rails `generate` command on an existing Rails website to make a new controller.

I checked out the repository to my local system but when I try to run the `generate` command I get the following error:

```
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:
2:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby/lib/ru
by/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/1.9/mysql2.so (LoadError
)
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysq
l2/mysql2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysq
l2.rb:9:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysq
l2.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.
rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.
rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.
rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.
rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.
rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.
rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb:132:i
n `require'
        from C:/Users/dboliver/Desktop/Assorted Items/RB_OLTARIS/branch/rails_3_
dev/config/application.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands
.rb:24:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands
.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You should run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Comment: I've still been getting this error even after using bundle

Comment: Ok, you should use `bundle exec rails generate` instead of `rails generate` to load the gems in your project.

Comment: Still getting the same errors..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get Rails Server to work with MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799777/cant-get-rails-server-to-work-with-mysql)

Comment: Have you installed Mysql developer extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure MySQL is running, you can run

```
mysql.server start
```

command to confirm

and then, run

```
bundle install
```

to verify MySQL gem is installed too